# how to get a value inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

what am i doing wrong here? i want to get the new beers value with console.log but it is keeping giving me **undefined** here ist have already tried  can someone help me on this?

```
var beers;
function attached() {
    var inquiryUrl = baseUrl + "/ProviderSingle?$top=8";
    $.getJSON(inquiryUrl, function (viewModelFromServer) {
        beers = JSON.stringify(viewModelFromServer.value);
    });
}

console.log(beers);
```

Comment: The call is asynchronous, so you're loging before you set beers. log from the callback.

Comment: @kougiland by giving `async:false` your code may work....

Comment: you making async call inside your function.make use of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)link

Comment: @james async:false is invalid $.getJSON(inquiryUrl, async:false, function (viewModelFromServer) {

Comment: @kougiland I forgot specify that, you need to use `$.ajax` to use `async`. `$.getJSON` is the shorthand version of `ajax` it doesn't provide that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $.getJSON is an asynchronous call. It wont wait for the complete event to happen. Try like

```
function attached() {
var inquiryUrl = baseUrl + "/ProviderSingle?$top=8";
$.getJSON(inquiryUrl, function (viewModelFromServer) {
    beers = JSON.stringify(viewModelFromServer.value);
    console.log(beers);
});
}
```

---

Asynchronous means that the code doesn't perform in a queue (sync does):

```
alert( 1 );
alert( 2 );
alert( 3 );
```

These will always do `1,2,3`, they are synchronous. The following code is asynchronous:

```
alert( 1 );
$.getJSON(inquiryUrl, function (data) { alert( 2 ); });
alert( 3 );
```

Lets say the ajax-call takes 1 second. The alerts will go `1,3` and 1second after this codes starts the async ajax-call is ready and will alert the `2`

Comment: i want to use it outside of the attached i didn't downvote you answer by the way

Comment: @kougiland by giving async:false your code may work...

Comment: @kougiland - are you getting value as Anoop Joshi suggested?

Comment: @NikhilButani: the OP wants to place the `console.log` outside of the `attached` function.

Comment: @Nikhil Butani yes i am getting the value like that but that is not what i want

Comment: Yes @Qantas94Heavy got that, but need to confirm that function returning value or not?

Comment: @NikhilButani: sorry, not quite sure what you mean. An asynchronous function usually doesn't return a value (apart from promises). If you're referring to `attached`, it doesn't return a value.

Comment: @kougiland Why would you want to use it outside of the ajax function? The only logical place to have it is in the success callback of the ajax request. You could always refactor it to call a different function onsuccess if you are concerned with the legibility of the code

Comment: @heymega because codes are more readable then. Also, promise is quite recommended for cleaner code

Answer (score 1):

Use promise to correctly update the values.

```
var beers;
var promise = null;
function attached() {
    var inquiryUrl = baseUrl + "/ProviderSingle?$top=8";
    promise = $.getJSON(inquiryUrl);
}

promise.done(function(data) {
    beers = JSON.stringify(data.value);
    console.log(beers);
});
```

Comment: promise  is a good idea but your code is somehow not working http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: This might not, I've just jotted down the logic for promise, which is right.

Comment: See following working example. Change your code accordingly http://jsbin.com/haqetere/1/edit